# Where did the spies' family live in Eretz Yisroel?

Tags: parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies, bava-batra, yehoshua-joshua, kaleb-caleb

Rashi [Bamidbar (14:38)](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.14.38.1?lang=bi) quotes a Gemara [Bava Basra (118b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.118b.3?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) that Yehoshua and Kalev took the spies' portion of land in Eretz Yisroel.

> ויהושע וכלב … חיו וגו'. מַה תַּ"ל חיו מן האנשים ההם? אֶלָּא מְלַמֵּד
> שֶׁנָּטְלוּ חֶלְקָם שֶׁל מְרַגְּלִים בָּאָרֶץ וְקָמוּ תַחְתֵּיהֶם
> לַחַיִּים (בבא בתרא קי"ח):  ויהושע וכלב ... חיו וגו׳ AND JOSHUA AND
> CALEB LIVED [FROM THOSE MEN] etc. — What is the force of חיו מן האנשים
> ההם (does it not state later on, Numbers 26:65, ‘‘And there was not
> left a man of them save Caleb the son of Yephuneh and Joshua the son
> of Nun)"? But the phrase teaches that they received the portion of the
> spies in the Land and thus remained alive, so to speak, in their stead
> (i.e. the text does not intend to state that they alone of all those
> men remained alive, but that they lived “from” the other men, i.e.
> from their portion in the Land) (Bava Basra 118b).

Where did the spies' family live if they didn't have land? Did Kalev/Yehoshua rent them the space or was the extended family wiped out?

Comment: Been a while since I studied the sugya (in Yesh Nohelin) but I seem to recall that though the meraglim did not inherit, their children did inherit on the merits of their grandparents